# Ошибка при запуске Telegram-бота на Python

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

При запуске, насколько я понимаю, рабочего кода с использованием telebot-а, бот не запускается, а в консоли появляется большое кол-во ошибок (приложил фото с ошибками) [image: Фото с ошибками]
Я новичок в питоне, в интернете ответ не нашёл.. 
Эта проблема появляется у всех ботов,которых я пишу. В чём проблема, как исправить?
(Прикладываю код)
[image: Фото с кодом]
В файле config.py только токен.

Comment: Проверьте интернет соединение. У вас сразу вылетает или позже?

Comment: Вылетает по-разному: иногда через 2 секунды, иногда через 8-10. Интернет соединение в норме.

Comment: роскомнадзор? Попробуйте с прокси

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import telebot
from telebot import apihelper

bot = telebot.TeleBot(bot)
apihelper.proxy = {'https': 'socks5h://LOGIN:PASS@IP:1080'}
```

https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI#proxy